# Extract Hash Address from URL

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a url saved in a variable that contains a hash address:

```
url1="https://some.com/ofthis/addr1vxu5xx7nyrqh9gku9530c9mme"
url2="https://some.com/ofthis/addr1vxu5xx7nyrqh9gku9530c9mme/8638ffe0/moreof/that"
```

I would like to extract the address part of this url, meaning it always starts with "addr1" and **ends at the following "/"** (there could be no slash after the address like in $url1 or there could be an unknown number of slashes be following like in $url2. The first pattern "addr1" must be included, while everything from the first following "/" must be excluded.

So I just want exactly this part:

```
addr1vxu5xx7nyrqh9gku9530c9mme
```

I tried to do this with sed and almost got there, but there is a space between the first pattern "addr1" and what is following:

```
echo "$url2" | sed -e 's/.*\(addr1\)\(.*\)\/.*/ \1 \2/'
```

if i use this with $url1 I get:

```
https://some.com/ofthis/addr1vxu5xx7nyrqh9gku9530c9zaf4tydnelcg0erqd03wa6laqkctmme
```

It does not start at "addr1".

I use this with $url2 I get:

```
addr1 vxu5xx7nyrqh9gku9530c9zaf4tydnelcg0erqd03wa6laqkctmme/8638ffe0/moreof
```

First, there is a whitespace between "addr1" and the rest of the string.
Second, It cuts off from the last "/" in the url.

EDIT: a URL could also have typical special caracters like & or ? following the address. I guess the regex would need something that stands for / OR ? OR &. Maybe there is a class for special characters?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "$url1" | cut -d'/' -f5
addr1vxu5xx7nyrqh9gku9530c9mme

$ echo "$url2" | cut -d'/' -f5
addr1vxu5xx7nyrqh9gku9530c9mme
```

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` and a regex:

```
[[ $url2 =~ addr[^/]* ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
```

Output:

```
addr1vxu5xx7nyrqh9gku9530c9mme
```

Answer (score 1):

Cycling through OP's 4x scenarios wtih parameter substitution:

```
for url in 'http://some/stuff/addr1XYZabcdef123' 'http://some/stuff/addr1XYZabcdef123?def=xyz' 'http://some/stuff/addr1XYZabcdef123&some other stuff' 'http://some/stuff/addr1XYZabcdef123/ignore/this/stuff'
do
    addr="addr1${url//*addr1/}"     # strip everything up to and including "addr1"; append new "addr1" on the front
    addr="${addr//[\/?&]*/}"        # strip everything from any of the 3x chars '/' '?' '&' to end of line
    echo "${addr}"
done
```

This generates:

```
addr1XYZabcdef123
addr1XYZabcdef123
addr1XYZabcdef123
addr1XYZabcdef123
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add spaces in replacement:

```sh
echo "$url2" | sed -ne 's/.*\(addr1[^\/]*\).*/\1/p'
```

**Results**: `addr1vxu5xx7nyrqh9gku9530c9mme`

**REGEX EXPLANATION**

```sh
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character (0 or more times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    addr1                    'addr1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\/]*                   any character except: '\/' (0 or more times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character (0 or more times)
```

Comment: wow, thanks, that worked :) What if after the address could be either nothing, a / or a special character like ? or &. Is there a regex class that could be used for special characters?

Comment: @Phil Yes, `[^\/?&]`, `sed -ne 's/.*\(addr1[^\/?&]*\).*/\1/p'`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this.

```
echo "$url" | sed -E 's|https:.*(addr1[^/]*).*|\1|'
```